# How to search in commits in repositories with specific language in github?

Tags: api, github, search

I want to search github with the following syntax:

`<commit-message> language:c++`

In other words, I want to know how to search for a specific string() from commit logs of repositories written in c++.

I've already searched in github web site with

`q=<commit-message> language=cpp type=Commits`

but it seems the target repositories are not mainly written in c++.
Am I wrong with the search api usage? Or just searching with language and type options not work?
Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The search "[`l=&q=remove+"set+-e"+language%3AC%2B%2B&type=Commits`](http://h?l=&q=remove%20%22set%20-e%22%20language%3AC%2B%2B&type=Commits) won't take the language part into account.

The [Advanced Search](https://github.com/search/advanced?q=remove%20%22set%20-e%22%20language%3AC%2B%2B) proposes languages for Repository, but not code (or commit message) search.